# Unity desktop on Raspberry Pi 2

Tags: drivers, unity, qt, raspberrypi, mesa

The first thing needed to make it work is a driver. There was a Mesa and DRM driver for Broadcom VC4 developed recently by Eric Anholt. It's an OpenGL driver.

http://dri.freedesktop.org/wiki/VC4/

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EXDeketJNdk

Has someone except the author got it to work?

P. S. What I am seeing:

- defconfig for bcm2835 does not compile at all, so I stick with modified bcm2709_defconfig (well, maybe I've messed up the rebase of the Ubuntu, rpi and driver branches on the 4.1-rc3 kernel)

  ```
  arch/arm/Kconfig:312:error: recursive dependency detected!
  arch/arm/Kconfig:312:   choice <choice> contains symbol ARCH_AT91
  arch/arm/Kconfig:365:   symbol ARCH_AT91 depends on ARCH_MULTI_V4T
  arch/arm/Kconfig:823:   symbol ARCH_MULTI_V4T depends on ARCH_MULTIPLATFORM
  arch/arm/Kconfig:317:   symbol ARCH_MULTIPLATFORM is part of choice <choice>
  ```

  and

  ```
  In file included from arch/arm/kernel/asm-offsets.c:21:0:
  ./arch/arm/include/asm/glue-df.h:99:2: error: #error Unknown data abort handler type
   #error Unknown data abort handler type
    ^
  In file included from arch/arm/kernel/asm-offsets.c:22:0:
  ./arch/arm/include/asm/glue-pf.h:54:2: error: #error Unknown prefetch abort handler type
   #error Unknown prefetch abort handler type
    ^
  ```
- why there is a guide to building an X server on http://dri.freedesktop.org/wiki/VC4/ ? It looks like a default one.
- to test the thing I use Qt5 qml examples from the qtdeclarative5-examples package with xfce4 DE. It doesn't act as like some driver is installed.

  ```
  $ LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/qt5/examples/quick/demos/clocks/clocks 
  libEGL warning: DRI2: failed to authenticate
  libEGL warning: DRI2: failed to open swrast (search paths /usr/local/lib/dri)
  Cant find EGLConfig, returning null config
  Unable to find an X11 visual which matches EGL config 0
  Could not initialize OpenGL
  Aborted
  ```